# extract human vocals from song

Tags: python, algorithm, audio, signal-processing, voice

my question is about how to proceed in extracting human voice in music using the language python
i have gone through this code but it extracts background music

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

# read in audio file and get the two mono tracks
sound_stereo = AudioSegment.from_file(myAudioFile, format="mp3")
sound_monoL = sound_stereo.split_to_mono()[0]
sound_monoR = sound_stereo.split_to_mono()[1]

# Invert phase of the Right audio file
sound_monoR_inv = sound_monoR.invert_phase()

# Merge two L and R_inv files, this cancels out the centers
sound_CentersOut = sound_monoL.overlay(sound_monoR_inv)

# Export merged audio file
fh = sound_CentersOut.export(myAudioFile_CentersOut, format="mp3")
```

i need to extract human voice in song

if not this then how to subtract one audio file from another audio file

Comment: When you say "extract" do you mean "keep" or "remove"? Your code is subtracting (adding the inverse is same as subtract).

Comment: i want to keep human voice and to remove background music

Comment: OK so your code is subtracting L and R and this retains the background music (removes the vocal) - so instead you should add the two channels together (i.e. don't do the inverse) then you will get the vocal. It may be that the vocal is in different proportions in left and right channels, so you should maybe have a play with the proportions of each - vary b between 0 and 1 (or more practically 0.3<=>0.7) and work out L*b+R*(1.0-b) to see which does the best job of removing the music/retaining the vocal.

Comment: Or follow this guide using Audacity: https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_vocal_removal_and_isolation.html

Comment: @barny, what do you mean by " add the two channels together", wouldn't that just result in the same audio file? could you please explain? Thanks!

Comment: Read the audacity link.

Answer (score 14):

You can always use the librosa library, which is favorite library for audio processing in python.
It can be helpful in separating vocals (and other sporadic foreground signals) from accompanying instrumentation.

https://librosa.github.io/librosa_gallery/auto_examples/plot_vocal_separation.html

It takes the slice and plot the same slice, but separated into its foreground and background

To save the extracted foreground, you can use:

```py
import librosa.output
import soundfile as sf
new_y = librosa.istft(S_foreground*phase)
sf.write("new-audio.wav", new_y, samplerate=sr, subtype='PCM_24')
```

Comment: how to save the generated S_foreground ?

Comment: @MaryamRahmaniMoghaddam I'll write the code for saving the new audio in the answers section

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer to the question mentioned in the comments of the answer above:

> how to save the generated S_foreground? *@MaryamRahmaniMoghaddam*

At first, import librosa and soundfile:

```py
import librosa
import soundfile as sf
```

Then, add the following code at the end of the python file:

```py
new_y = librosa.istft(S_foreground*phase)
sf.write('file.wav',new_y,samplerate=sr,subtype='PCM_24')
```